# Orchard Taxonomy Term Autoroute Tokens

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

I'm trying to create a custom URL for a blog post in Orchard 1.6. I want to have the Taxonomy section term as part of the URL.

```
http://my-site.com/my-blog/section-term/my-post
```

Using taxonomies, I can easily list and separate the blog posts into their respective sections without hassle.

The Autoroute rule I'm trying to use is:

```
{Content.Container.Path}/{Content.Fields.BlogPost.Section}/{Content.Slug}
```

The first part `{Content.Contianer.Path}` isn't so important, I can do without if it's easier; however the `{Content.Fields.BlogPost.Section}` simply doesn't generate anything at all.

Am I doing something wrong? Or is this a bug I will need to report?

Thanks, Rhys.

**Update**

Okay so I didn't look hard enough, there is already a bug filed for this one: http://orchardtaxonomies.codeplex.com/workitem/61

Answer (score 2):

This has not been resolved in changeset 2bd61b0ec84a.

Issue has also not been resolved within:
Orchard Taxonomies Module commit e688a1b34b01 Mar 10, 2012 (1.x branch)

- Orchard Taxonomies Module commit 2bedcd7ba4f3 Feb 20, 2013 (default branch)
- Orchard commit 71d81e849620 Jul 9, 2013 (1.x branch)
- Orchard commit f65d032a9b0c Apr 30, 2013 (default branch)

My tests were conducted with the following steps:

- Create taxonomy named "test"
- Attached taxonomy field "test" to content type "Page" using field name "testfield"
- Under "testfield" checked "Allow only one term to be selected"
- Under Autoroute (within "Page" content type) checked "automatically generate when editing content"
- tried all of the below tokens within the autoroute pattern in between publishing a page with a taxonomy selected:

  - {Content.Fields.Page.testfield}/{Content.Slug}
  - {Content.Fields.Page.testfield.Terms}/{Content.Slug}
  - {Content.Fields.Page.testfield.Terms:0}/{Content.Slug}
  - {Content.Fields.Page.test}/{Content.Slug}
  - {Content.Fields.Page.test.Terms}/{Content.Slug}
  - {Content.Fields.Page.test.Terms:0}/{Content.Slug}

I manged to get taxonomy tokens working in the current unreleased version of 1.7 (I assume it would work with 1.6 too) by utilising the following posts within https://orchardtaxonomies.codeplex.com/workitem/61:

- mrtn_t wrote Feb 19 at 7:33 AM
- BrentCarter wrote Apr 30 at 4:24 AM

Just to clarify, when you add the taxonomy token make sure you use the field name of the taxonomy, not the taxonomy name itself (unless the taxonomy name and field name are named the same, then you're ok).